# How to search from API based on text inputs in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

when i search from API based on keyword,i get all details in API. i need get only details based on the text input from search.. i dont know the problem is in my API or My code... please help me..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            value:'',
            value2:''                                                                                                           
        };
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.crimeChange=this.crimeChange.bind(this);
    this.search=this.search.bind(this);

    }
    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({value:event.target.value});
    }

    crimeChange(event) {
        this.setState({value2:event.target.value});
    }
    search(){
        let {value, value2 } =this.state;
        const url=`https://api.myjson.com/bins/e69i9/?i=${value}&q=${value2}`;

        fetch(url,{
            method:'GET'
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json =>console.log('details',json));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form >
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4">

                            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="police station">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                <option value="areacode">Areacode</option>
                                <option value="changaramkulam">Changaramkulam</option>
                                <option value="edakkara">Edakkara</option>
                                <option value="edavanna">Edavanna</option>
                                <option value="kadampuzha">Kadampuzha</option>
                                <option value="kalikavu">Kalikavu</option>
                                <option value="kalpakanchery">Kalpakanchery</option>
                                <option value="karipur">Karipur</option>
                                <option value="karuvarakundu">Karuvarakundu</option>
                                <option value="kolathur">Kolathur</option>
                                <option value="kondotty">Kondotty</option>
                                <option value="kottakkal">Kottakkal</option>
                                <option value="kuttippuram">Kuttippuram</option>
                                <option value="malappuram">Malappuram</option>
                                <option value="manjeri">Manjeri</option>
                                <option value="mankada">Mankada</option>
                                <option value="melattur">Melattur</option>
                                <option value="nilambur">Nilambur</option>
                                <option value="pandikkad">Pandikkad</option>
                                <option value="parapanangadi">Parapanangadi</option>
                                <option value="perinthalmanna">Perinthalmanna</option>
                                <option value="perumpadappu">Perumpadappu</option>
                                <option value="ponnani">Ponnani</option>
                                <option value="pookottumpadam">Pookkottumpadam</option>
                                <option value="pothukkal">Pothukkal</option>
                                <option value="thanur">Thanur</option>
                                <option value="thenhipalam">Thenhipalam</option>
                                <option value="thirurangadi">Thirurangadi</option>
                                <option value="tirur">Tirur</option>
                                <option value="valanchery">Valanchery</option>
                                <option value="vazhakad">Vazhakad</option>
                                <option value="vazhikadavu">Vazhikadavu</option>
                                <option value="vengara">Vengara</option>
                                <option value="vandoor">Vandoor</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <div className="form-group is-empty">
                                <input type="number" placeholder="Crime Number" className="form-control" value={this.state.value2} onChange={this.crimeChange}/>
                                <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <button type="button" 
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                            onClick={()=> this.search()}
                            >Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Search;
```

this my api data

// 20180312234820 // https://api.myjson.com/bins/e69i9/

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "police station": "perinthalmanna",
    "crime number": 97,
    "details": {
      "image": "http: //asianetindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/jayanandan.jpg",
      "name": "john",
      "section of law": "IPC200",
      "type of person": "missed"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "police station": "tirur",
    "crime number": 98,
    "details": {
      "image": "https: //themmindset.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/chota-shakeel.jpg",
      "name": "mohan",
      "section of law": "Ipc407",
      "type of person": "suspects"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "police station3": "ponnani",
    "crime number": 99,
    "details": {
      "image": "https://themmindset.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/mukhtar_ansari.jpg",
      "name": "rooney",
      "section of law": "ipc207",
      "type of person": "criminals"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "police station": "kolathur",
    "crime number": 100,
    "details": {
      "image": "https://themmindset.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/abu_salem.jpg",
      "name": "tipper vasu",
      "section of law": "Ipc408",
      "type of person": "missed"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "police station": "kottakkal",
    "crime number": 101,
    "details": {
      "image": "https://themmindset.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/abu_salem.jpg",
      "name": "killer",
      "section of law": "Ipc402",
      "type of person": "suspected"
    }
  }
]
```

the concept is ... if i select a policestation and crime number,then will get details based on that from API...

please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code that allows multiple filtering of data from the response.The result is shown in the console.

```js
class TestJS extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={
          value:'',
          value2:'',
          resultFound : false,
          filteredData : ""
      };
      this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.crimeChange=this.crimeChange.bind(this);
      this.search=this.search.bind(this);
      this.multiFilter=this.multiFilter.bind(this);
  }

   multiFilter(array, filters) {
      const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
      // filters all elements passing the criteria
      return array.filter((item) => {
          // dynamically validate all filter criteria
          return filterKeys.every(key => !!~filters[key].indexOf(item[key]));
      });
  }

  handleChange(event){
      this.setState({value:event.target.value});
  }

  crimeChange(event) {
      this.setState({value2:event.target.value});
  }
  search(){
      let _this = this;
      let {value, value2 } =this.state;
      const url=`https://api.myjson.com/bins/e69i9/?i=${value}&q=${value2}`;

      fetch(url,{
          method:'GET'
      }).then(response => response.json())
          .then(function(data){
              console.log(data, value, value2);
              let filters = {
                  "police station" : [value],
                  "crime number" : [parseInt(value2)]
              };
              let  filtered = _this.multiFilter(data, filters);
              console.log(filtered);
              if(filtered.length <= 0){
                _this.setState({resultFound : false})
              }
              else{
                _this.setState({filteredData : filtered, resultFound : true})
              }
          });
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <form >
                  <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-md-4">

                          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="police station">
                              <option selected>Choose...</option>
                              <option value="areacode">Areacode</option>
                              <option value="changaramkulam">Changaramkulam</option>
                              <option value="edakkara">Edakkara</option>
                              <option value="edavanna">Edavanna</option>
                              <option value="kadampuzha">Kadampuzha</option>
                              <option value="kalikavu">Kalikavu</option>
                              <option value="kalpakanchery">Kalpakanchery</option>
                              <option value="karipur">Karipur</option>
                              <option value="karuvarakundu">Karuvarakundu</option>
                              <option value="kolathur">Kolathur</option>
                              <option value="kondotty">Kondotty</option>
                              <option value="kottakkal">Kottakkal</option>
                              <option value="kuttippuram">Kuttippuram</option>
                              <option value="malappuram">Malappuram</option>
                              <option value="manjeri">Manjeri</option>
                              <option value="mankada">Mankada</option>
                              <option value="melattur">Melattur</option>
                              <option value="nilambur">Nilambur</option>
                              <option value="pandikkad">Pandikkad</option>
                              <option value="parapanangadi">Parapanangadi</option>
                              <option value="perinthalmanna">Perinthalmanna</option>
                              <option value="perumpadappu">Perumpadappu</option>
                              <option value="ponnani">Ponnani</option>
                              <option value="pookottumpadam">Pookkottumpadam</option>
                              <option value="pothukkal">Pothukkal</option>
                              <option value="thanur">Thanur</option>
                              <option value="thenhipalam">Thenhipalam</option>
                              <option value="thirurangadi">Thirurangadi</option>
                              <option value="tirur">Tirur</option>
                              <option value="valanchery">Valanchery</option>
                              <option value="vazhakad">Vazhakad</option>
                              <option value="vazhikadavu">Vazhikadavu</option>
                              <option value="vengara">Vengara</option>
                              <option value="vandoor">Vandoor</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-md-4">
                          <div className="form-group is-empty">
                              <input type="number" placeholder="Crime Number" className="form-control" value={this.state.value2} onChange={this.crimeChange}/>
                              <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-md-4">
                          <button type="button"
                                  className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                                  onClick={()=> this.search()}
                          >Search</button>
                      </div>
                      {!this.state.resultFound ? <div> No Data Found!!</div> : 
                        JSON.stringify(this.state.filteredData)}
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
export default TestJS;
```

Comment: error:{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 63,
  "colno": 13
}

Comment: @kasim521 It will not run here you will have to run it with reactjs on your machine may be. It’s working and I have tested it. Please use some environment where you have reactjs in place.

Comment: @kasim521 - If your issue is resolved please mark the answer as verified so it will help other people facing the same issue.

Comment: great sir..i have one question.If i enter irrelevant data in text input(data which not includes in API) then how to show not found.

Comment: please help me sir..i can show the data in the console.How to show the fetched data on the web page.

Comment: @kasim521 - I've made changes to above snippet. I'm not sure about your exact requirement but the above code displays the NO data found and if the result is found it will display the result. Hope it helps you. Thanks!

Comment: great sir..sir, I want to display the data one by one, not in JSON format.I want to display in this order.`first:image based on text input``second:name` etc...how to display sir? I hope you will answer...thank you sir

Comment: @kasim521 - I had just printed it in JSON format to show you how it display the result. No the only thing you have to do is iterate over the output JSON and render the output in web. You will be able to do it  by referring some simple example about render HTML with the help of JSON.